# Registration form doesn't send data to database

Tags: php, mysql

So I made this registration form but it won't send the data to my database, it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't, it is really weird. here is the code.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'Users');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

$con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
$db = mysql_select_db('Users', $con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

function NewUser()
{
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $efternamn = $_POST['efternamn'];
    $email     = $_POST['email'];
    $password  = $_POST['password'];
    $query     = "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers (firstname,efternamn,email,password) VALUES ('$firstname','$efternamn','$email','$password')";
    $data = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($data) {
        echo "YOUR REGISTRATIOfafa";
    }
}

function SignUp()
{
    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Websiteusers WHERE email = '$_POST[email]' ") or die(mysql_error());
        if (!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
            NewUser();
        } else {
            echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...";
        }
    }
}

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    SignUp();
}



 <!DOCTYPE HTML> 
 <html> 
 <head> 
<title>Registrera Dig</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head> 
<body> 
<table style=" position:absolute; left:550; top:200;">
<form method="POST" action="signup.php"> 
 <tr> <p style=" position:absolute; left:555; top:163;" >Namn</p><td> <input type="text" name="firstname"></td> 
 </tr> 
  <tr> <td>Efternamn</td><td> <input type="text" name="efternamn"></td> </tr> 
  <tr> <td>Email</td><td> <input type="text" name="email"></td></tr> 
  <tr> <td>Lösenord</td><td> <input type="password" name="password"></td> </tr> 
  <tr> <td>Bekräfta lösenord </td>
  <td><input type="password" name="cpass"></td> </tr>
   <tr> <td><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Skapa konto"></td> </tr> 
    </form> 
 </table>


   </body>
  </html>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Update
So everytime I empty my table I am able to register again. but I can only register 1 time

Comment: Maybe provide a non-minified version...

Comment: what you mean, this is the entire form?

Comment: Hey Markus, welcome to StackOverflow! Please check [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hey this is the complete code for the page,

Comment: Asking generally "what's wrong" might open a can of worms on you. You're not formatting your code properly (PHP part reads like a mess). You're using an obsolete mysql lib (not safe, and the lib is removed from the latest PHP version). You're inserting user submitted data directly into the queries (not safe). You're mixing english and swedish in your db schema. You're using tables for layout

Comment: I mean that it would help if you properly indent your code, have one statement per line, etc...

Comment: Yes JimL I recognise that there are many bad things that can be changed, but still these problems should not affect the sending of data to the database

Comment: unfortunately I can't change it obe

Comment: Also add what happens when it's not working. Do you get an error? Do you get empty entries in the database? etc.

Comment: I only get a blank page, nothing happens on the database, no entries nothing

Comment: Just reading your code needs a lot of time and concentration.

Comment: yeah I am really sorry for not lining it up better

Comment: @Markus Why can't you change it? Just click on "edit" and fix it...

Comment: Do you fill all the form fields, each time you submit your form?

Comment: yup just saw it fixing it now

Comment: yes Devman I fill all form fields

Comment: Here we go.Wasn't that much difficult, was it?

Comment: yeah hope it is easier to read now, you guys see any solution?

Comment: The only thing I can say is that there should be something wrong with your $_POST['email'] field. Just echo something out in the first line of your SignUp() function to see if it gets executed or not?

Comment: Ohhhh don't do this if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    SignUp();
}

Comment: instead check one of your fields or send a hidden input

Comment: I echoed and it worked

Comment: what do you mean send a hidden input

Comment: Do you know something like this:  <input type="hidden" name="somehidden" value="my-hidden"> ??  It's weird that you just getting a blank page. If your function gets executed than you should end up with something echoed out on your screen.

Comment: yeah sure, so you think that can fix it?

Comment: if I replace the (isset($_POST['submit'])) { SignUp(); }  with a hidden input

Comment: It's weird that you just getting a blank page. If your function gets executed than you should end up with something echoed out on your screen

Comment: yes exactly and if there is something wrong I should get an error

Comment: Even your HTML is not showing up?

Comment: what you mean? the form shows up and I fill in the info

Comment: if you mean when I click register, no not even html

Comment: alright look I discovered a new thing

Comment: I mean after you submit the form. You said that you end up with a whole white page.

Comment: everytime I empty my table I am able to register again

Comment: yes only a white page

Comment: but everytime I empty my database table I am able to register again

Comment: Your id is not auto increment ohhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: Change it and you're good to go .

Comment: unfortunately it is auto increment lol

Comment: What a shame. But I'm sure It's about your database structure.

Comment: yeah maybe, I don't know what it can be I'm going crazy

Comment: I would try to split this line: "if (!$row = mysql_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error())) {" into multiple lines... don't combine "!", "=", and "or" in the same condition. Split it up and see what happens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has so many problems, I just re-created it for you using best practices. Where you went wrong was the following:

1.Using MySQL (A depreciated class)

2.Vulnerable to SQL injection

3.You don't need functions, it's just as clean if you don't have them. You're only calling the code once.

4.Inserting $_POST[email] is not a good idea and probably won't work.

5.Fixed multiple other problems such as tags

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'Users');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

$con = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); //Use MySQLi as MySQL is depreciated.

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //No need for functions, do it all here as otherwise you'll have to declare globals.
    if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $query = mysqli_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM Websiteusers WHERE email = ?"); //Preparing the SQL query (We don't insert values directly into the query)
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "s", $_POST['email']); //Bind the email to the SQL query
        mysqli_stmt_execute($query); //Execute the query
        mysqli_stmt_store_result($query); //Store the results
        if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($query) != 0) //Is the number of rows 0?
        {
            //rows
            echo "SORRY...YOU ARE ALREADY REGISTERED USER...";
        }
        else
        {
            //No Rows
            $query = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO WebsiteUsers (firstname,efternamn,email,password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"); //Preparing the SQL query (We don't insert values directly into the query)
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query, "ssss", $_POST['firstname'], $_POST['efternamn'], $_POST['email'], $_POST['password']); //Bind the params to the SQL query
            mysqli_stmt_execute($query); //Execute the query
            echo "YOUR REGISTRATIOfafa";
        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Registrera Dig</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head> 
<body> 
    <table style=" position:absolute; left:550; top:200;">
        <form method="POST" action="signup.php"> 
            <tr> <p style=" position:absolute; left:555; top:163;" >Namn</p><td> <input type="text" name="firstname"></td> </tr> 
            <tr> <td>Efternamn</td><td> <input type="text" name="efternamn"></td> </tr> 
            <tr> <td>Email</td><td> <input type="text" name="email"></td></tr> 
            <tr> <td>Lösenord</td><td> <input type="password" name="password"></td> </tr> 
            <tr> <td>Bekräfta lösenord </td>
            <td><input type="password" name="cpass"></td> </tr>
           <tr> <td><input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Skapa konto"></td> </tr> 
        </form> 
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OMG thank you sooooo much for taking the time to help. It works perfect now. great that there are people that are willing to help :D

Comment: ok so just a tiny issue right now is that I always get you are already a registered user

Comment: Should be fixed, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

i would simplify your code and remove conditions. Shorter code will make it easier to debug and then check line by line what's happening.

A blank screen is weird unless it's something to do with the way you've set up error handling? Do u get any other warnings of something basic goes wrong? To test maybe you should try writing a line of code that definitely gets an error such as including a file that doesn't exist? Do you then get an error ? If not, it's something to do with the way you've configured your error reporting ... This doesn't solve the problem, but will bring you a step closer as when u actually get the error displayed you'll find out why the DB is not registering your form data.